# I cannot make this regular expression work

Tags: php, regex

May be it's simple but I cannot do it work.
I have two filename strings:
wrap.html
wrap-popup.html

I try to select both using 
`/.*wrap.*\.htm.*/ mask` 
But it only matches the first one "wrap.html".
If I use `/.*wrap.+\.htm.*/`, it only matches the second one "wrap-popup.html"

I thought * sounds 0 to infinite characters.
What's the correct mask to select both strings ???

Comment: Your first regex matches [both](https://regex101.com/r/dU4qV1/1).

Comment: Please post an complete code example, which demonstrates the problem you have. The current question contains too little specifics, giving us way too many alternatives as to what may be the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the string "this is text with 2 html pages: wrap.html and wrap-popup.html"

The first regex `/.*wrap.*\.htm.*/` will match that whole string.

So if you don't want to include the first part of the string then you need to remove the first .*

Now `/wrap.*\.htm.*/` will match "wrap.html and wrap-popup.html" from the string.

That's because the first .* is a greedy match.

So when we change the regex to `/wrap.*?\.html?/` the .*? is now a lazy match. And the `l?` is an optional `l`. So the regex will return "wrap.html".

But if we want to retrieve both we need a global search, or it would only find the first match.

A preg_match_all (instead of preg_match) with the regex `/wrap[\w\-]*?\.html?/` will match both "wrap.html" and "wrap-popup.html".

That second regex of yours wouldn't match wrap.html because with the `.+` it expected at least 1 character between "match" and the dot.

Comment: The question is tagged with PHP. Why `/g`?

Comment: Probably because I coded more in Perl ;p.  Fixed now.